# IBM Worklight 6.0 - jQuery Mobile widgets palette does not show up

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-rpe

I am designing using jQuery Mobile, but the widgets palette does not show. I did include the script of jquery and jQuery Mobile in my header.

It is quite strange that sometimes it shows, sometimes it does not.

Comment: Worklight version...?

Comment: And just in case, what jQuery Mobile and jQuery core version are you using? Are you using uncompressed versions of those?

Comment: The worklight version is v6.0. JQuery Mobile version is 1.3.1. The JQuery core is 1.9.1. No uncompressed versions are included.

Comment: Given so, files look correct. Would you mind providing your main web page code? Can you look at your Error Log (Window -> Show View -> Error Log) to identify if there is any error when the palette does not load?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the answer in this question: [IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - jQuery palette does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497284/ibm-worklight-6-0-0-1-jquery-palette-does-not-show-up)

When using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 the palette will display however it will not display if using 1.3.2; this is fixed internally for the upcoming Worklight 6.1.0 release.

---

See if the provided steps help in showing up the jQuery Mobile Widgets palette.
Also as Orlando suggested in the comments above, if you get any errors in the Erros view in Eclipse when the palette contents is missing, please edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

the jquery mobile widget palette works when you add the normal jquery files and not the minified version of the jquery files.
the pallet seems to work if you have addded the non minified files to your .html file.