# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - jQuery palette does not show up

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-rpe

In my Worklight project I can't get jQuery palette, it's always hidden. I searched, tried... No result. HTML and Dojo palettes are OK.

Configuration:

- Eclipse Juno EE,
- Worklight 6.0.0.1,
- Installed IBM jQuery Mobile tools (comes with Worklight),
- jQuery-1.10.2 and jquery.mobile-1.3.2

Note: I was getting errors while trying to install Worklight directly from Eclipse so on the end i download it as a zip and installed that way.

Update: I added picture I found of jQuery palette. Please note that it's not the same as HTML or Dojo palette
[jQuery palette image](http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-lpUEnuQcFBM/UmWKfEEuPtI/AAAAAAAAFC4/i4eMThB35Lc/w999-h536-no/Untitled.png)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** the `jQuery Mobile Widgets` palette fails to open, it seems, when using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2, but works with 1.3.1. The below was updated.

---

I've done the following and the palette showed up for me. See if you've done the same, or if I am missing a step from what you've done.

1. Installed Worklight 6.0.0.1 from the Eclipse Marketplace on Eclipse Jave EE 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)
2. Downloaded jQuery Mobile 1.3.1
3. Created a new Worklight project > new application
4. Used the wizard to add an application with jQuery Mobile support
5. Added the images folder and the files jquery.mobile.1.3.1.js and jquery.mobile.1.3.1.css
6. Opened myapp project\apps\myapp\common\myapp.html
7. Clicked the palette button

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9Dzw.png 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. What you did is one of combinations I tried. The result is the same - you have HTML palette but not jQuery. Tomorrow I can try with older version of jQuery, for now from home I'll just update question with picture of jQuery palette I found on the Internet, that way it will be more clear

Comment: @Darko, The jQuery Mobile Widgets palette will fail to display with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2, but does display with 1.3.1.You can probably just switch to 1.3.1 in the meanwhile.

Comment: You're right, moving from jQuery 1.3.2 to 1.3.1 does solve the problem. Thanks