# worklight design window not displaying anything

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-rpe

Worklight 6.0.0.201
Eclipse Juno 1.10.2.v2
JQuery 1.3.2

The design window is not displaying anything either on adding the jquery mobile widgets or even no default visible app name that shows when you enter the design mode.

PS: i have entered in the design mode. The mobile navigation tools are also not visible.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This used to be a problem with jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 when used in a Worklight project.
You can use either 1.3.1 or the latest 1.4.x release of jQuery Mobile and the various views in Eclipse will display appropriately.

For some background: [IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - jQuery palette does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497284/ibm-worklight-6-0-0-1-jquery-palette-does-not-show-up)